# How to disable physics/forces on box2d dynamic body?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a dynamic body that constantly changes linear velocity, I want my dynamic body to act like a kinematic body which is not affected by forces and can move in a linear way. But I need to use dynamic body because I need to detect collision.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `setLinearVelocity` method on your dynamic body in your `render` or `act` method - although it will be affected by gravity you will override it's velocity in every step and it will act like kinematic

Comment: Isn't that bad though? Setting linear velocity every frame? Is there another solution?